# Precision needed in definition of unboundedness

Tags: functions, definition

This is a quick question about what it means for a function to be unbounded. 
Does it mean that the function tends to + or - infinity, or does it just mean that it has no limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither.  It means that there does not exist a value $M>0$ such that for all $x$,  $f(x)\in [-M,M]$.  In other words,  the range of the function cannot be bounded.   Note that the function CAN still have a limit at infinity that is bounded, as the unbounded behavior can occur someplace beforehand.  For example, consider the function $f(x)=\frac 1 x$ on $(0,\infty)$.  This is unbounded as the closer you get to 0, the bigger $f(x)$ gets, but the limit exists as $x\to \infty$ and is $0$

Edit to answer the comment:  For an unbounded function that still can be
integrated,  take a piecewise defined function,  with the main part being any integrable function (For now we'll use the constant 0, for simplicity) and the "rare" part being that on the natural numbers,  $f(n)=n$.  (In Lebesgue integration, this would be called a set of measure 0, as it is countable).

$\int _0 ^\infty f(x) dx=0$,  as we can create a partition such for any $\epsilon >0$, we surround each natural number with an interval no bigger than $\frac \epsilon {n 2^n}$.  Then the contribution of that part of the integral to our Riemann sum is $n \cdot \frac \epsilon {n 2^n}=\frac \epsilon {2^n}$, and adding up all of those over the natural numbers, we get $\epsilon$.  (And of course the integral on the other parts 0)

It's unbounded obviously it can be as big as any natural number.

The short summary here is, yes it can be integrable as long as the unbounded behavior is sufficiently "small"

Comment: ok, I think I understand, thanks for the response :) Do you happen to know of any functions that are unbounded, but whose integrals from 0 to infinity still exist?

Comment: Technically,  in the definition of a proper Riemann integral,  we need a function to be bounded.  If you're talking about an improper Riemann integral which is defined in terms of limits, then yes,  $f(x)=\frac 1 {x^2}$

Comment: But $1/x$ isn't finite when you put in the limits 0 and infinity

Comment: Oh, right.   Hrm,  got me when I'm first awake,  I was thinking series and not integrals.

Comment: Got it,  editing the answer for the function

Comment: @ThanksABundle: In order to be (improperly) integrable, a function must have limit $0$ towards $\infty$. On the other hand, it may be unbounded at finite distance, like $\frac {\mathbb{e}^{-x}} {\sqrt x}$, the integral of which is $\sqrt \pi$.

Comment: @AlexM. As long as the unbounded behavior is in the form of jump discontinuities, that's not true.   The value of a single point doesn't change the riemann integrable, so we can add any countable amount of jump discontiniuties and still have it be integrable,  and the limit will not tend to 0 (As in my example above)